# How to enable recurring payments for sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring

How to enable recurring payments for sandbox account?

Last time I used sandbox, I enabled it by request on https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox/enable-reference-transaction-sandbox
Thread is locked and it points to developer.paypal.com. I created there test accounts, and even imported old accounts from old version of sandbox. But I can't find how to enable recurring payments, as it's disabled by default.

So, how could I test recurring payments?

Comment: Did you read the page you linked?  It points you to https://developer.paypal.com/ for more information.

Comment: I read, and I registered on developer.paypal.com. I created there test accounts, and even imported old accounts from old version of sandbox. But I can't find how to enable recurring payments, as it's disabled by default.

Comment: You should say that in your question. ^^

Comment: [This blog entry](http://randallhook.com/2010/02/04/keys-to-configuring-the-paypal-sandbox-for-recurring-payments/) walks you through how to enable them on the new paypal developer site.

Answer (score 1):

I have set this up before

I searched around and found some instructions

1. Create a test account as a normal seller, not pro, via the deveoper.paypal.com interface
2. Log into the sandbox (sandbox.paypal.com) using the new test account
3. Make sure you are in the My Account section of the site by clicking the My Account main menu tab
4. Click on the sub menu "Profile"
5. Under the Financial Information column click the link for "Recurring payments dashboard"
   6 .On the right hand side click the link for "Sign up for Enhanced Recurring Payments"
6. Click the Agree and Continue button

This link shows how to implement it:

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/942/kw/recurring%20payments

Comment: 1) I logged in developer.paypal.com with my real PayPal account (it's required).
2) After, I opened Applications -> Sandbox accounts - http://grab.by/loBM
3) Created new seller test account http://grab.by/loBU
4) There is nothing useful in profile/notifications sections.
5) Opened 'Sandbox site' link (see previous screenshot), I thought I'll be able to login there with my new test account - http://grab.by/loBY
6) Here I see only link 'PayPal Sandbox', which points to developer.paypal.com, where I could login only with my real account.. recursion.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Raadad Am getting a message Sorry, this feature is not available at this time. When tried recurring payment using automatic billing How can i solve this

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing API calls - I had to actually contact PayPal support and give them the sandbox (Merchant Pro) accounts I wanted working, you have to ask them to enable DPRP on those accounts.