# How to enable recurring payments for sandbox account?

Tags: paypal

I have been following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848191/how-to-enable-recurring-payments-for-sandbox-account). I get this error when I click on  "Sign up for Enhanced Recurring Payments" link:

> Sorry, this feature is not available at this time.

I have paypal test account .How can I activate Recurring Payments within this account?

Do I need any other type of account to use Recurring Payments??

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.paypal.com/mts and submit a ticket.  Let them know your sandbox account email address and they can get that enabled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go to http://www.paypal.com/mts but those tickets can take a while. Quickest way would be to call PayPal's Merchant services.