# PayPal Sandbox Recurring Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring-billing

I am trying to setup recurring payments in our SandBox.

I have followed the instructions here: 
[How to enable recurring payments for sandbox account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848191/how-to-enable-recurring-payments-for-sandbox-account)

I have a working Python Django code, have setup billing plans and foward the user to a billing agreement with an Activated plan but it errors on the PayPal page, that this is currently not possible.

So I checked the above link and understand I need to enable recurring payments in my facilitator sandbox account.

Once I go to the Recurring payments dashboard-> Sign up for Enhanced Recurring Payments

I only end up with a message saying: Sorry, this feature is not available at this time.

How am I supposed to test this now ? This Sandbox account is an Account type: Business and verified.

Comment: If you create a fresh business / pro sandbox account in your developer account it should have recurring payments enabled by default.

Comment: We figured out that it is not possible to do in Germany. Its only a feature for US,UK, New Zealand and Canada. Unless you make 5k + and it seems it works with the Manager and Partner. So we dropped this and went with Stripe instead. But I am not 100% sure on this. But this is what we understood.